# Force reload component in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to re-create and animate the same view back when navigated to same page.

```
this.routerExtension.navigate(['/home']);
```

Currently if i am in home page and button is tapped in same page which fires the above code, the component is not reloaded. I want to forcefully reload and animate the same view into stack.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of a hack, but I got around this by making two routes that refer to the same component, something like '/home' and '/home1', then alternating which one I used.

It would be nice if there was an option in routerExtension to do this.

Comment: i did the same way to temporarily solve the problem. But i was expecting an elegant solution. Unfortunately. didn't find any other way...

Comment: I did something similar in nativescript-vue, but since the naviagtion is broken in nativescript-vue, when the user press the back button it switches back to the same page. So unless there's a way to edit the navigation backstack, I'm screwed